# DataFrame transformations using information from group_by

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have dataset for binary classification that looks like this:

```
group_id    pos_in_group    ...    target
...         ...                    ...
172          0                      0
172          1                      0
172          2                      1
172          3                      0
172         ...                    ...
172         719                     0
```

So happens that in group only one record can have `target == 1` and those are more likely to happen at first positions. But model used for prediction doesn't account for that. So there may be several records with predicted `target == 1` in one group.

```
group_id    pos_in_group    ...    target
...         ...                    ...
172          0                      0
172          1                      0
172          2                      1
172          3                      0
172          4                      1
172          5                      0
172         ...                    ...
172         719                     0
```

With `df[df['target'] == 1].groupby(['group_id'])['pos'].min()` I can get first occurrence of `target == 1` in each group. How I can use that to assign `target == 0` to all records with higher position in each group?

Also, how using `1 / df.groupby(['group_id'])['target'].sum()` can I scale column in each group by different value?

Comment: with `['pos']` you mean column `['pos_in_group']`?

Comment: Yes, I just shortened it in text.

Comment: with `df.groupby(['group_id'])['pos'].min()` you would get the first row in this case. But `target == 1` is in row 3. What is your goal exactly? Because with that code you are not getting the first occurrence of `target == 1`

Comment: Yes... that was a typo, sorry. Of course I need first to filter `target == 1`

Comment: Scaling can be done using this: `df['target'] = df.groupby('group_id')['target'].apply(lambda t: t / t.sum())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly.
For your first question you can use `df.groupby.min` and after that fill `target` column conditionally with `np.where`:

```
target_min = df[df.target == 1].groupby('group_id').pos_in_group.min()

df['target'] = np.where(df.pos_in_group.isin(target_min), 1, 0)

print(df)
   group_id  pos_in_group  target
0       172             0       0
1       172             1       0
2       172             2       1
3       172             3       0
4       172             4       0
5       172             5       0
6       172           719       0
```